# How to read from a json log file in a shell script .sh file and get the analytics data by counting the number of occurance in the log file

Tags: bash, shell, jq

Need to read data from a json log file and get analytics data from that using shell script.

**log file contains json as below:**

```
{
info: 'label1',
description: 'some desc',
timestamp: '2016-07-27T06:24:50.335Z'
}
{
info: 'label2',
description: 'some desc',
timestamp: '2016-07-27T06:24:50.335Z'
}
{
info: 'label2',
description: 'some desc',
timestamp: '2016-07-27T06:24:50.335Z'
}
{
info: 'label2',
description: 'some desc',
timestamp: '2016-07-29T06:24:50.335Z'
}
{
info: 'label3',
description: 'some desc',
timestamp: '2016-07-29T06:24:50.335Z'
}
```

**I need the result as below (using shell script):**

```
Labels    Date                  Count

label1   2016-07-27             1
label2   2016-07-27             2              
label2   2016-07-29             1
label3   2016-07-29             1
```

This is as far I could go, need some suggestion on how to approach.\

```
#!/bin/bash
my_dir=`dirname $0`
file="out.log"
#keysFile="$my_dir/keys.txt"
for log in $(cat $file | jq '{id: .info,time: .timestamp}'); do
#This is as far as I could get. I was able to read the data in the form of {id: 'label1', time: '2016-07-27T06:24:50.335Z' }
#Now I need to somehow create a key value thing in shell and store timestamp / label as key and increment the count
echo $log
done
```

Comment: so... what did you try? Have you played with `jq`?

Comment: Once you have posted a question, also provide sample code or snippets that you have tried. If possible you could also point out sections in the code that are throwing errors. The SO community will be able to help you once you provide these details, rather that just a QA forum.

Comment: @KartikKannapur Updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Given your input, you could create that as csv data using this:

```
$ jq -rs '
def to_csv($headers):
    def _object_to_csv:
        ($headers | @csv),
        (.[] | [.[$headers[]]] | @csv);
    def _array_to_csv:
        ($headers | @csv),
        (.[][:$headers|length] | @csv);
    if .[0]|type == "object" then
        _object_to_csv
    else
        _array_to_csv
    end;
map({ label: .info, date: .timestamp[:10] })
    | group_by(.)
    | map(.[0] + { count: length })
    | to_csv(["label", "date", "count"])
' input.json
```

This yields:

```
"label","date","count"
"label1","2016-07-27",1
"label2","2016-07-27",2
"label2","2016-07-29",1
"label3","2016-07-29",1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach which uses **reduce** instead of **group_by**.

Assuming your data is in `out.log` and the following filter in `filter.jq`

```
["Labels", "Date", "Count"], 
["", "", ""], 
(
  reduce .[] as $r (
      {}
    ; [$r.info, $r.timestamp[0:10]] as $p
    | setpath($p;getpath($p)+1)
  )
  | tostream
  | select(length==2)
  | flatten
)
| @tsv
```

you can run

```
jq -M -s -r -f filter.jq out.log
```

to produce tab-separated output

```
Labels  Date    Count

label1  2016-07-27  1
label2  2016-07-27  2
label2  2016-07-29  1
label3  2016-07-29  1
```